# occasional esc is not a function in ejs

Tags: javascript, html, express, ejs

i am have trouble figuring out this problem of mine,
here is part of my ejs code

```
<div class="row">
      <% for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) { %>

        <div class=<%if(posts.length>1){%>"col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6"<%}else{%>"col-sm-12" <%}%> >
          <div class="thumbnail col-sm-12 col-md-12">

            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<%= posts[i].file[0].buffer.toString('base64') %>" />
            <div class="caption">
              <h3><%= posts[i].title %></h3>
              <ul>
                  <li>Product Type: <%= posts[i].category %></li>
                  <li>Suburb: <%= posts[i].suburb %></li>
                  <li>Description: <%= posts[i].description %></li>
                  <li>Target: <%= posts[i].target %></li>
              </ul>
              <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Details</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% }; %>
    </div>
```

it displays a bunch of product information including a image, but sometime i get typeError - esc is not a function, and sometimes it works fine.
I notices the problem is with the line:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<%= posts[i].file[0].buffer.toString('base64') %>" />
```

if i remove this line of code, it will work every time.(no image of course)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This usually triggers when an object is undefined within an ejs template, which might be the reason in your case.

Check whether you have a value in `posts[i]` in every iteration. That solves the issue.